# How to use $ selector in a for loop?? Can't use $("#i")

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

```
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    a[i] = val($("#i"));
    alert(a[i]);
    }
```

UPDATE:
This code is wrong, as it selects element with id(#) 'i'. Thus cannot use "#i".

My question was:
How to iterate 'i' in the '$'selector inside for loop??

Comment: `a[i] = val($("#"+i));`

Comment: Instead of numbered IDs you should use a class and `$(".theclass").each(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your variable this way :

```
 a[i] = val($("#"+i));
```

In your case, you're using 'i' as a string, not a variable.

You must use '+' to concatenate your string and your variable.

Comment: Please explain his mistake and why this way it would work. This increases the quality of your answer.

Comment: Thanks @user:5547026 and (cannot add second user) for helping. I got the mistake.

Comment: I was not sure if I can concat inside $, your cleared my doubt. I need not tell that it worked.